# How to send generics over UDP connection C#?

Tags: c#, udp, byte, converters, send

I'm wondering is there a way to send some kind of generics for example `List <float> floatValues = new List<float>()` need to be sent to udp client. I don't know how to do that, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize `floatValues` using some serialization facility (like [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)) and than deserialize it back.

Or you can create your own "application level protocol" and put to the stream type name and serializer type and use this information during deserialization process.

Comment: actually I have to translate generics to little endian then send them, before that I need to do something with list.

Comment: You can serialize the whole list and send it. I think little endian and big endian make sense when you have different platforms: for example, serializing using .NET and deserializing in C++.

Comment: @TimTaker: what kind of examples do you need? There is a plenty of examples in the web on any kind of serializer. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is known as [serialization/deserialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

> In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission, serialization, is the process of converting a data structure or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment

Instead of building your own serializer, I would recommend to use one of the existing libraries like
[XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), 
[SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx), 
[BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx), 
[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) ,
[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), 
[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx),
[Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/),
[ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text),
[Protobuf.Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) ........

Here is an example using Json serialization

```
//Sender
string jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(floatValues);
byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

//Receiver
string receivedJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesToSend);
List<float> floatValues2 = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                                         .Deserialize<List<float>>(receivedJson);
```