# How to convert little endian to big and send it over UDP?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, endianness

I need to conver little endian which is float to the big and send them through UDP. The code snipped receives coord data and assigns it to the float array, then converts to the byte data array and finaly should be send over UDP connection but it doesn't work!

```
public void SendUDP()
    {
        try 
        {
            lockObj.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {   
                foreach(CoordData datam in coordDataList)
                {
                    float[] dfv = {datam.X, datam.Y, datam.Z, datam.Alpha, datam.Theta, datam.Phi};

                    /*
                    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.Y);
                    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.Z);
                    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.Alpha);
                    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.Theta);
                    data = BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.Phi);
                */
                data = BitConverter.GetBytes(dfv);  
                Array.Reverse(data);    

                }
                client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint); 

            }
                finally
                {
                lockObj.ExitReadLock();

                }

                }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580567/how-to-send-generics-over-udp-connection-c)?

Comment: There is a built-in function to do this....I would use that.

Comment: @L.B, there are no endianness

Comment: @TimTaker Because if you use some serializer, it will handle all of those stuff for you.

Comment: @L.B, but my end point to where is Udp pockets sending couldnt deserialize my serialization, is it possible use serializer which couldn't be deserialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for the problem:

```
    int width = sizeof(float);

    int nDataIndex = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[myData.Count * width];

        for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count; ++i)
        {
            byte[] converted = BitConverter.GetBytes(myData[i]);

            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(converted);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            { 

                data[nDataIndex+j] = converted[j];          
            }
            nDataIndex+=width;
        }

        client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are reversing the entire array of floats. You need to reverse the bytes of each *individual* float.

In fact, what you wrote in your question won't even compile since there is no overload of `BitConverter.GetBytes` that takes an array.

What you'd have to do (other than use the library functions that exist to handle this for you) is something like this:

```
List<byte> myData = new List<byte>();

myData.AddRange(Array.Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.x));
myData.AddRange(Array.Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(datam.y));
//....etc....

byte[] bytesToSend = myData.ToArray();
```

Comment: in this way I'm having an error: The best overloaded method match for `System.BitConverter.GetBytes(bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @TimTaker: As L.B. above has already stated, there are methods in the library that take care of all these problems for you. But to make your solution work, you would have to go through each individual value, `GetBytes`, reverse that array of bytes and then add it to your final array that you intent to send. As you can see, it's kind of a pain. Which is why there are libraries to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to make sure your value is correct for your environment.